# How can I integrate a credential json file with GCP bigquery with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a file type of json. It is a credential file. I want to integrate with `GCP bigquery` and access to `GCP bigquery` using this credential file with Nodejs.

How can I do that?
How can integrate with `GCP bigquery` using credential file in nodejs?
How can I test the result of integration to test integration is valid or not?

Comment: To get started follow the lessons in this Google Code Lab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bigquery-nodejs

Comment: See [crisp-bigquery](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery) for both credential [usage](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/blob/master/server/src/api/models/BigQueryModel.ts#L420) and intergration [tests](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/blob/master/server/src/test/BigQueryModel.test.ts).

Comment: Will your node app run on Google Cloud or elsewhere?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Are you asking OP or me?

Comment: @winwiz1, I'm asking Daniel_FA. Sorry, I forgot to mention.

Comment: @ guillaume blaquiere  my need is integrating third parties with GCP bigquery so at the first i should authenticate to GCP bigquery, how can i ensure i could conecct bigquery successfully?

Comment: First: i should authenticate to bigquery

Comment: Second: i should make sure for authentication.

Comment: Third: i should connect third party to bigquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the `keyFilename` attribute, unless I've misunderstood your question.

[This GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#node.js) talks about authenticating using a service account key file.

So if your credentials file lived in `/var/my_credentials.json` (dumb path but whatever), your Node.js code would look something like this:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const options = {
  keyFilename: '/var/my_credentials.json',
  projectId: 'my_project',
};

const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);
```

Also consider: keep the contents of that credentials file in Google Secret Manager and use `gcloud secrets versions access latest`, dumping the output into a temporary json file local to the script, then remove the temporary json file after it's no longer needed by the script. No need to have credentials floating around on servers.